# Can i use drag and drop from other window? Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, drag-and-drop, webdriver

I want to put jpg in dropzone from other window.
Can I do that?
In my test I open new window (my html with jpg) and I want to drag and drop it to dropzone on my main window.

I have error:
Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document.

Maybe there is another solution for placing this file eg from a disk?

I've tried several ways, including loading from a file from the disk and sending it using send keys.

Comment: Are you able to do that _Manually_ ?

Comment: Yes. By doing this manually I have the option to add a file to the dropzone or by clicking on the dropzone the file explorer window appears.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by creating a script in AutoIT.